# Source reader and custom non-seekable byte stream

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation, asf

I'm implementing a custom `IMFByteStream` to stream video over a network, but the problem is that I cannot pass its object to the source resolver to create media source, because the `CreateObjectFromByteStream` is returning an error:

> 0xc00d36ee : The provided bytestream was expected to be seekable and it is not.

Of course my custom byte stream is not seekable because seeking over the network is not possible. So the question is how can I create a media source using a non-seekable byte stream? My final destination is to create a `IMFSourceReader` object. The type of the source content is ASF.

Comment: You need a media source which is fine with a non-seekable stream. It is the whole point that some sources need seeking and they check the caps to make sure seeking will be available.

Comment: Content type of my destination media source is ASF. It is possible to create ASF media source that doesn't need a seekable byte stream?

Comment: I presume all seeks are "forward", so it would most likely be possible to implement a trivial seek for a stream (just read off the unwanted data)

Comment: Currently i'm trying to create a bypass like this, but the position is setting to 0, even when previous was eg. 1024. So i don't think all seeks are forward.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented two `IMFByteStream` interfaces, one is called MediaByteStream which is used for non-storage memory streaming and the other is called StoreByteStream (yes I know) which is used for in-memory storage.

Placing the code below in your `IMFByteStream` implementation will eliminate your seekable error and have no effect on your ability to stream.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the characteristics of the byte stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pdwCapabilities">Receives a bitwise OR of zero or more flags. The following flags are defined. [out]</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the operation.</returns>
        HRESULT MediaByteStream::GetCapabilities(
            DWORD *pdwCapabilities)
        {
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;

            // Stream can read, can write, can seek.
            *pdwCapabilities = MFBYTESTREAM_IS_READABLE | MFBYTESTREAM_IS_WRITABLE | MFBYTESTREAM_IS_SEEKABLE;

            // Return the result.
            return hr;
        }
```

You can if you wish to implement the `Seek` method of the `IMFByteStream` interface, but in your case (Network streaming) you can just return the seek position.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Moves the current position in the stream by a specified offset.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="SeekOrigin">Specifies the origin of the seek as a member of the MFBYTESTREAM_SEEK_ORIGIN enumeration. The offset is calculated relative to this position. [in]</param>
        /// <param name="qwSeekOffset">Specifies the new position, as a byte offset from the seek origin. [in]</param>
        /// <param name="dwSeekFlags">Specifies zero or more flags. The following flags are defined. [in]</param>
        /// <param name="pqwCurrentPosition">Receives the new position after the seek. [out]</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the operation.</returns>
        HRESULT MediaByteStream::Seek(
            MFBYTESTREAM_SEEK_ORIGIN SeekOrigin,
            LONGLONG                 qwSeekOffset,
            DWORD                    dwSeekFlags,
            QWORD                    *pqwCurrentPosition)
        {
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            _seekRequest = true;

            // Select the seek origin.
            switch (SeekOrigin)
            {
            case MFBYTESTREAM_SEEK_ORIGIN::msoCurrent:
                // If the buffer is less or same.
                if ((qwSeekOffset + _position) < size)
                    _position += qwSeekOffset;
                else
                    _position = size;

                break;

            case MFBYTESTREAM_SEEK_ORIGIN::msoBegin:
            default:
                // If the buffer is less or same.
                if (qwSeekOffset < size)
                    _position = qwSeekOffset;
                else
                    _position = size;

                break;
            }

            // Get the current position in the stream.
            *pqwCurrentPosition = _position;

            // Return the result.
            return hr;
        }
```

Comment: Only when I saw your solution I saw my problem.
Instead of setting *pdwCapabilities, I was returning the or in the HRESULT.

Answer (score 0):

Your failure supposedly comes from:

> [During the creation of the media source, the source resolver creates a byte stream for the file from which the media source reads the ASF content. In order for the time conversions to be successful, the byte stream associated with the ASF file must have seeking capabilities; otherwise, the application gets the `MF_E_BYTESTREAM_NOT_SEEKABLE` error from the Begin... call.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663577)

You might try media source [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206738), but it more looks like a mandatory requirement that the byte stream is seekable. One thing you can do to work this around is to indeed mark the stream implementation as seekable, and implement a wait once there is a read request from position which is not yet available.

Comment: But the position in a seekable byte stream can be set everywhere. So I would have to buffer all the data that I received. It is impossible.

Comment: Seekability requirement is typically for a reason. You are working with a source which assumes a finite byte stream. You either adapt your code to imitate seekability, to extent possible or you need to switch to scheme handler and full featured network source (as opposed to byte stream). When the byte stream carries progressive download style data, there is a good chance that seeking is only within small system (format, metadata) range and it is followed by sequential reads for the payload.